# TypeScript and Axios response type

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am using axios to talk to my APIs, and I wrapper it with a HTTClient class to avoid depend much on it:

```js
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import https from 'https';
import { stringify } from 'qs';

class HttpClient {
  private static instance: AxiosInstance;

  constructor() {
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.ENDPOINT_API,
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      }),
    });

    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    axiosInstance.defaults.paramsSerializer = this.paramsSerializer;
    axiosInstance.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => response.data);

    HttpClient.instance = axiosInstance;
  }

  public static getInstance = () => {
    if (!HttpClient.instance) new HttpClient();

    return HttpClient.instance;
  };

  private paramsSerializer = (params) => stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' });
}

export default HttpClient.getInstance();
```

As you will notice, when I do

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => response.data);
```

I'm returning the content of `data`. The issue is that now **the type** of the response is wrong.

```
interface TypedResponse {
  name: string
}

const response = await HttpClient.put<TypedResponse>(`/`);
const response.name // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'TypedResponse'.ts(2339)
```

TypeScript is thinking that `name` is within `data`, like this:

```
// Response
{
  data: {
    name: string;
  }
}
```

Which of course is wrong, as I'm not returning `data` anymore:

```
// Response
{
  name: string
}
```

How can I change the default axios response type in my class?

Comment: Can you change the structure of response...?

Comment: Have you tried typing the variable instead? i.e. `const response: TypedResponse = ...`

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi no, I dont want to change the structure of the response. I want to avoid `data.data.etc.`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I would like to modify the response type, not the type of the variable where I stored the data